# DataDog Package does not exist

Tags: java, maven, import, datadog

## The Problem

I try to import DataDog dependencies with Maven and `mvn clean install` prints:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project datadog_api_call: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/projects/path_to_maven_project/datadog_api_call/src/main/java/list_monitors/App.java:[2,30] package com.datadog.api.client does not exist
```

I created a simple maven project with `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart` in order to use the [DataDog API](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/?code-lang=java).
Added the following to the pom.xml like the documentation instructs:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.datadoghq</groupId>
  <artifactId>datadog-api-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.16.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

## What I've tried:

Changing the pom.xml file in various ways and run `mvn clean install` and `mvn clean compile`:

- With and without the `<packaging>jar</packaging>` line
- With both `<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>` & `<url>mvnrepository.com</url>` and without the urls
- With wrapping the dependencies in the dependencyManagement tag and without it
- With `<scope>compile</scope>`, `<scope>test</scope>` and without scope

Maven should find the package, import it and my java code should be able to resolve the package import.

Comment: Where did you put the `<dependency>` in your `pom.xml`? Note: It should be under `<dependencies>` and not under `<dependencyManagement>`.

Comment: It is under <dependencies> and didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Today I was facing the same problem, I placed my maven dependencies for Sprite and GSON after all my dependencies, but I was getting the error package com.google.gson.Gson and package com.stripe.Stripe does not exist. So what I did was place them before all the dependencies and trust me it worked.

Comment: The error prints are gone until I execute the java code and the console prints the same error message again

Comment: Enable logging that will help to figure out what's the problem. Spring logs are too long so the terminal can't display the entire log sometimes so you can go to the surefire reports inside the target folder. If the log is too long only check the lines that are suffixed with caused at

Comment: Try adding this to your application.properties logging.level.org.springframework.web=debug